# 3-sat and Tutte polynomial

Tags: graph-theory, z3, topology, z3py, satisfiability

Please consider the following 3-SAT instance and the corresponding graph

[image]

The graph can be displayed in other two forms

[image]

The Tutte polynomial for this graph is

[image]

The independence number of the graph is 4, then the considered 3-SAT instance is satisfiable. This fact is checked using the code:

```
x1, x2, x3 = Bools('x1 x2 x3')
s=Solver()
s.add(Or(x1,x2,Not(x3)),Or(x1,Not(x2),x3),Or(Not(x1),x2,x3),Or(Not(x1),Not(x2),Not(x3)))
print s
print s.check()
m = s.model()
print m
```

and the corresponding output is:

```
sat
[x3 = False, x2 = False, x1 = False]
```

The corresponding complement of the graph is

[image]

and the Tutte polynomial for the complement of the graph is

[image]

The clique number of the complement is 4 and then it says that the considered 3-SAT instance is satisfiable.

The question is :  It is possible to use the Tutte polynomial to decide if the considered 3-SAT instance is satisfiable ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other example:

[image]

The Tutte polynomial is:

[image]

The independence number of the graph is 3, then the considered 3-SAT instance is satisfiable. This fact is checked using the code:

```
x1, x2, x3, x4 = Bools('x1 x2 x3 x4')
s = Solver()
s.add(Or(Not(x1),x2,x3),Or(x1,Not(x2),x3),Or(Not(x1),x2,x4))
print s.check()
m = s.model()
print m
```

and the corresponding output is:

```
sat
[x3 = False, x2 = False, x1 = False, x4 = False]
```

The corresponding complement of the graph is

[image]

and the Tutte polynomial for the complement of the graph is

[image]

The clique number of the complement is 3 and then it says that the considered 3-SAT instance is satisfiable.

Answer (score 2):

Other example:

[image]

the graph can be displayed in other two forms:

[image]

The Tutte polynomial for this graph is:

[image]

The independence number of the graph is 3, then the considered 3-SAT instance is satisfiable. This fact is checked using the code:

```
x, y, z = Bools('x y z')
s = Solver()
s.add(Or(x,y,z),Or(Not(x),Not(y),Not(z)),Or(x,Not(y),Not(z)))
print s.check()
m = s.model()
print m
```

and the corresponding output is:

```
sat
[z = False, y = True, x = False]
```

The corresponding complement of the graph is

[image]

and the Tutte polynomial for the complement of the graph is

[image]

The clique number of the complement is 3 and then it says that the considered 3-SAT instance is satisfiable.

The question is : It is possible to use the Tutte polynomial to count  the possible models for the considered satisfiable  3-SAT instance?